# Geolocator does not response

Tags: c#, xaml

I tried this code:

```
private async void setMyPosition()
    {

        Geolocator gl = new Geolocator();
        Geoposition gp = await gl.GetGeopositionAsync();
        Debug.WriteLine("My longitude is: "+ gp.Coordinate.Point.Position.Longitude);
        MyPosition = gp;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("MyPosition");
        CalculateDistances(MyPosition);
    }
```

According to [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.geolocator.aspx), this should give me my gps position. But it doesn't. There is no crash, no error, no exception. Program execute GetGeopositionAsync() function with no result. When I surround this with try-catch, after while it gives me exception "Time limit expired" or something like that. I tough that geolocation system just do not answer right in the moment, but it is almost week now and still no response.

I spent with this topic few last hours and with no results. Supposedly code shared by Microsoft should be fine. How can I find out where is problem? Thanks in advance for any advices.

Comment: Please share more of your code: How does the whole method you wrote look like? If you use `await` you must be writing a `async` method,  and that method only returns a promise. If you want to wait for the result, you must call `.Result` in some place in your code. I'm missing that place currently. Furthermore, "According to documentation" - please share a link to the documentation you refer to.

Comment: To add more, what `Geolocator` are you using? I presume `Windows.Devices.Geolocation` but it is not visible from your post.

Comment: I just edited my question. Yes, I am using `Windows.Devices.Geolocation`. Documentation, I added link to, is one of two of my sources. The other one I cannot find again, sorry. But it was some ms tutorial or msdn for sure. I didn't use this `.Result`, but I guess it may be the source of few my troubles.

Comment: It might help (as always if you make some technical trial-and-error thing) to reduce your code to the simplest you can imagine, that is in this case, remove asynchronity. Just call `gl.GetGeopositionAsync().Result` and see what you get there. If that works, the issue is not about geolocation but about how you built asynchronity into your code. :-)